# Find control inside Listbox.ItemTemplate (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseevent, selecteditem

I have some problems finding the right `TextBlock` control inside a `StackPanel`. 
My markup:

```
<ListBox Name="lstTimeline" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TwItemStyle}"
         MouseDoubleClick="lstTimeline_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=lstTimeline, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <Border Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  BorderBrush="White"
                        BorderThickness="1" Height="48" Width="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ThumbNail, IsAsync=True}" Height="48" Width="48" />
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Name="stkPanel" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="0,4,0,0" FontSize="14"
                               Foreground="#c6de96" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApproximateTime}" FontSize="14"
                               FontFamily="Georgia" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="#BBB" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScreenName}" Name="lblScreenName"  FontSize="14"
                               FontFamily="Georgia" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="#BBB"
                               Loaded="lblScreenName_Loaded" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My double click code:

```
private void lstTimeline_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = (lstTimeline.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);

    StackPanel item = lbi.FindName("stkPanel") as StackPanel;
    if (item != null)
        MessageBox.Show("StackPanel null");
    TextBlock textBox = item.FindName("lblScreenName") as TextBlock;
    if (textBox != null)
        MessageBox.Show("TextBlock null");

    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

But the `StackPanel` is null.  How do find the right `TextBlock` in `SelectedItem`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you binding the ItemsSource of your ListBox? I don't see it being set in XAML. Are there actually items in your ListBox? If not then you will always get a null with the code you have

Answer (score 12):

```
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(lstUniqueIds.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lstUniqueIds.SelectedIndex));
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
CheckBox target = (CheckBox)myDataTemplate.FindName("chkUniqueId", myContentPresenter);
if (target.IsChecked)
{
    target.IsChecked = false;
}
else
{
    target.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Function `FindVisualChild` can be found on the MSDN page [FrameworkTemplate.FindName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx):

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon. That worked great for me, but it took me quite a while to figure out that "FindVisualChild" is a method you have to write yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

Comment: findName method  is  not   available in  Windows Phone??

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific function to use when you're looking for something whose name is defined in a template.  Try it like this:

```
private void lstTimeline_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = (lstTimeline.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);

    StackPanel item = Template.FindName("stkPanel",lbi) as StackPanel;
    if (item != null)
        MessageBox.Show("StackPanel null");
    TextBlock textBox = Template.FindName("lblScreenName",item) as TextBlock;
    if (textBox != null)
        MessageBox.Show("TextBlock null");

    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: StackPanel returns null (Value = null)

Comment: Code incomplete. What is `Template`?

Comment: Template in the above code is this.Template, or ListBox.Template -- although it could be any object with a template.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to xml with a get and set model.

```
var item = ...

            lstTimeline.SelectedIndex = -1;
            lstTimeline.ItemsSource = item;
```

Comment: I solved it with this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7d2b4134-e460-4daa-86b7-24a629d77718