# How to change run-time list box image path in wp7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have one list box and this list box contain image control.

I want to chane run time image path on click event of list box item.

How can i change my image control path ?

My code is like this:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="TransactionList" Width="450" Height="450" Margin="0,0,0,0">    
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="450" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="300" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,1,10">
                    <TextBlock Height="35" Width="250"  Margin="10,0,0,90" Text="{Binding SONGNAME}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Red" Name="tbSubCategories" />
                    <TextBlock Height="25" Margin="-250,10,180,30" Text="SingBy:" FontSize="18" Foreground="Gray" Name="tbsingby" />
                    <TextBlock Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="210" Margin="-180,50,0,70" Text="{Binding  SINGBY}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Gray" Name="tbSingBy" />
                     <TextBlock Height="25"  Margin="-280,60,200,0" Text="MusicBy:" FontSize="18" Foreground="Gray" Name="tbMusicby" />
                     <TextBlock Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" Margin="-205,100,0,30" Text="{Binding MUSICBY}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Gray" Name="tbMusicBy" />
                </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,50,0,35">
              <Image Name="imgsubcatagorie" Width="40" Height="40"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Source="/VodafoneAugmentedReality;component/Images/play1.png" />
            </StackPanel>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to change imgsubcatagories image control path when i click on list box item.
Help me

Comment: Can any one know this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, that's not quite easy.

If *can* get your image object, that could be easily done like this:

```
imgsubcatagorie.Source = ModifyImageSource(new Uri("yourUri", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

 private ImageSource ModifyImageSource(Uri uri)
        {
                image = new BitmapImage(uri);
                return image;          
        }
```

---

However, you can't just take this object. The main problem is how to get it.

You should somehow pull it from TransactionList. (also, you have a quite heavy construction: listbox=>stackpanel=>stackpanel=>image)

My first idea was: use loop to go through all items in TransactionList and try to find image there.

---

**Possible solutions**

I'm not well-expirienced with ListBox.ItemTemplate feature, and I don't have your whole code, but whatever...

Direct approach: try to use loop to find item.

```
foreach (var x in TransactionList.Items)
            {
                if (x is Image)
                {
                    image = (Image)x;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Then use this image object in event handler.

Also

[Find element of concrete type.](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7)

Also check this question:

[Find control inside Listbox.ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800101/find-control-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-wpf-c)

Not for wp7, but may work.

Comment: :my image is in listbox so imagename.source is not possible in click event of listbox

Comment: :Thanks for help i am very confused about that

Comment: :you are right but how can i get imagename its not possible in transectionlist click event.i want to change image path on transection list click event...actully i have another path but i am not able to get imageName

Comment: So, did something of this help? I've seen, you've been asking about way to get imagePath. P.S. If you reached comments limit, I recommend to delete some of them.

Comment: :thanks Olter for replaying but it is not working in this foreach loop if condition is not true.I mean when loop is not enter in if condition