# Deactivate SelectionChanged in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

With a regular ComboBox I would use the following code to deactivate the Selection Change.

```
<ComboBox Name="CbbTest" SelectionChanged="CbbTest_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>


CbbTest.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(CbbTest_SelectionChanged);
```

However, when my ComboBox is in a DataTemplate I am not able to access the ComboBox by name, and therefore I am not able to turn off the selection changed. 
How can deactivate ComboBox CbbTestTwo like in the previous code, but from a DataTemplate in the following code?

```
<StackPanel>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="CbbTestTwo" SelectionChanged="CbbTestTwo_SelectionChanged"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Any help in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you seek to be able to manipulate your combobox in the SelectionChanged event. You can get your combobox like this:

```
private void cbTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
            if(sender is ComboBox)
            {
                comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            }

        }
```

Can now handle it like that :

```
    private void cbTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
                if(sender is ComboBox)
                {
                    comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
                }
//Add the treatments you want
                comboBox.Items.Clear();
                comboBox.ItemsSource = listTest;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use more MVVM like approach which means subscribing directly on events in the code behind of the view is not the best option. In this case you could use a behavior like this.

```
public class ComboBoxSelectionChangedBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ....
    }


    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

And then you can attach this behavior through xaml. Here is a short tutorial on behaviors https://blog.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/

Answer (score -1):

[Find control inside Listbox.ItemTemplate (WPF C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800101/find-control-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-wpf-c#)

Please refer this link, from the above code snippet, once you will have the combobox instance, you can unsubscribe the event.